# Animate layers again when slide reappears

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexslider, animate.css

I am using flexslider as slider plugin and adding some layers in each slide and animating those layers with `animate.css`.

But once the layers are being animated they are not reanimating again when the slides are reappearing. I tried this using `addClass` and `removeClass` in JQuery but it is not working.

Can someone help me in this please ?

Comment: You should post codes that cause this issue

Comment: Here are the codes...
http://jsfiddle.net/ad8gt5wj/

Answer (score 0):

You might try setting the `animationLoop` configuration option to `true` instead of `false`.

You can also try this:

```
AnimatedElement.on('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',   
function(e) {
    //resetElement to initial state (reapply starting class)
});
```

Comment: Can you send a link to the page or some sample code?